# Environment dependent dispatch of protocols/multimethods in clojure

Tags: architecture, clojure

I'm facing a problem in how to architecture a particular piece of my software.
Lets say, I have a function called `make-temp-dir` (and many others) that does
some dark magic depending on the current OS. I want to be able to put the
implementations of these methods for each OS in a separate namespace.

Firstly, I believe protocols (if possible) or multimethods are the solution to
this. However, I've never seen an example of using these with implementations
spanning over multiple namespaces. And I'm not able to figure how this'd work
out.

Second, if I use protocols for this, I'll have to call the methods something
like

```
(make-temp-dir current-os arg-1 arg-2)
```

Somehow, passing the os as the first argument all the time doesn't look too good
to me. For semantic sake, I'd wish the `make-temp-dir` take intelligent
decisions depending on the OS. Sure I can use some macros and do something like

```
(doto current-os
  (make-temp-dir arg-1 arg2))
```

but that feels wrong.

How should this be done? Or am I going the wrong way? Any help appreciated.

**Edit**: Okay, thanks a ton to @kotarak, I managed to get something working. For anyone that stumbles on this, https://gist.github.com/2477120. Its working fine, I think I'll go with that. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(ns your.utils)

(def current-os)

(defmulti make-temp-dir
  (fn [& _] current-os))

(ns your.utils.mac)

(defmethod make-temp-dir :mac-os-x
  [a b]
  (...))

(ns your.utils.win)

(defmethod make-temp-dir :windows
  [a b]
  (...))
```

In your startup code you have to initialize `current-os` with `alter-var-root` before using any of the utility functions.

```
(let [os (find-os)]
  (alter-var-root #'current-os (constantly os))
  (require (case os
             :mac-os-x 'your.utils.mac
             :windows  'your.utils.win)))
```

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: So, the second piece of code needs to be under `your.utils` namespace right? Also, what is the `#'` reader macro - sorry, don't know how to google that either ;)

Comment: `#'` is called a *var quote*.  You can find a description of var quotes at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure/jDBAJD4nWqs.

Comment: @kotarak, Okay, awesome solution. Took me this long to digest it but I think I understand what's going on. I'd still like some input on my first comment though.

Comment: @user100464, Thanks for the link. Checking it out.

Comment: @kotarak, Does this solution require that all the implementation namespaces should be in the same file? Kinda defeats the purpose of having them in different namespaces no?

Comment: @ShrikantSharat Obviously it does not require all namespaces to be in the same file as the `require` indicates in the example. You can split the `let` block in `your.utils`. `(def current-os (find-os))` at the top. `(require (case current-os ..))` at the bottom of the file. This should get the correct flavours loaded, but may not play nice with AOT compilation. Haven't looked in there in detail. YMMV.

Comment: Yep, got it working. Posted a link to my implementation on the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain, but it sounds like you may end up reinventing a wheel that Java provides you with.  Try out https://github.com/Raynes/fs for a convenient wrapper on some of what Java provides beyond the basic tools in clojure.java.io ( http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.java.io ).

You may find also https://github.com/drakerlabs/milieu useful if your question extend beyond OS-specific branching to environment-specific configuration values.  I wrote this code as part of our proprietary projects here at Draker, and we've just recently released it as free software.  We haven't yet officially announced it to the community, but it is in Clojars and ready for use. Feedback is appreciated! The concept that drove its creation was environments in the sense of dev/test/staging/production etc, but I see no reason why it couldn't be used to configure variables for different OS environments as well.

Comment: Thank you for the links rplevy. I think the fs package will come in handy for me :)